# Word Document Overwritten With Background Image?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, data-recovery, file-recovery, overwrite

My cousin has called me quite panicked because she could not open a word (.docx) document after a hard reset of her computer. Office 365's Word was giving us the run around, one thing it suggested was to open the file with "[text recovery converter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word)", it did not open the document, said there was an error, with no diagnostic information, we attempted to open the document with Google Drive, but it only opened a blank document. The document still takes 300+ KB. I told her to download Libre Office, it opened it, but what we found was the background image of her desktop. Which makes me wonder if it is possible that the OS accidentally overwrote at least part of the document with the desktop background image as it was shut off at just the wrong time. She cant seem to get anything with "recovering unsaved files". *Might it be possible to recover any information from this document or the file itself?*

Comment: Did the user try here:  C:\Users\jusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\   ?   This location saves documents on a regular basis as well as if not saved.

Comment: @John Just took a look, she says they are all from 3 years ago. They are all from the same day too 

Comment: UPDATE: She did find a later backup, but still missing 50-100 pages